# css transform scale blur effect issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming, css-transforms

I'm trying to make an html div element zoom independent, so that it looks always of the same size, independently of the window zoom level.
I'm using the css property "transform: scale()" to scale it when the user zoom the page.

However, as the page is zoomed, the element becomes blurry. I've made some research on google and I've found that it might be due to the fact that css transform uses hardware acceleration, so the div is treated as an image, and it gets blurry because it is too big/small with respect to the current size.

Is there a way to eliminate this blur effect, or to scale the div without using hardware acceleration?
Otherwise is there another way to make the div zoom independent?

Comment: add css to the image or div -- transform: transale3d(0,0,0); -- OR -- transform: translateZ(0);  - to put the zoom on the hardware layer , that should stop the bluring -- i dont know another way without GPU usage

Comment: are you talking about mobile zoom or desktop zoom?

Comment: I'm talking about both

Comment: unfortunatly they work very diferently so they would need completly different approaches

Comment: you can try the new css image-rendering property but its not well supported yet and im not sure if its not using hardware -- http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images-3/#the-image-rendering

Comment: My priority is for mobile devices...if there is a way to solve this issue at least on mobile dev, then I'd study another solution for desktop zoom

Comment: can i ask. why is hardware acceleration an issue??. i had the same problem like many people and after spending months to resolve the blur the only thing that worked was to add (transform: translateZ(0);)

Comment: I've read that the issue is that css transformation is hardware accelerated, and so it has to transform the html element into an image. In this way, the element get blurry because the image is too small with respect to the scaling. Using transform: translateZ did not solve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: A strange behavior is that on desktop if I zoom out the page, the div gets blurry. If I reload the page (and hence the zoom level is the same), the div is displayed correctely